# Show Custom Links in Lightning Home Page

Tags: lightning-design-system

I have a custom lightning component in my home page "Salesforce Login" Now my scenario is whenever I am clicking this "Salesforce login" in my homepage, it should redirect me to salesforce login page. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is  "Salesforce Login" link in a your lightning component? If so please add code as well

Comment: You need to create a home page component and then from lightning app builder you need to place that component.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality using Standard Component Called **Rich text** available in Lightning App Builder.

All you need is to drag the standard component Rich Text on the home page and the write the link using rich text editor in right hand side of Lightning App builder.

Save the change and activate it. It will work excellently. Refer the image below:-

[image]

You don't need to create Custom component at all.

Comment: And if you use the "Link" button/functionality, you can use a label, e.g. to hide ugly URLs.